# "Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file" on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python-2.7, fonts, anaconda, networkx, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using python 2.7 on Anaconda, on Ubuntu 16.04, installed in a virtual machine with VMware Player on Windows 10.

When running the following code, I get the following error:

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> G = nx.complete_graph(4)
>>> pos = nx.nx_pydot.graphviz_layout(G)
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
```

I have tried setting the path as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492033/fontconfig-error-cannot-load-default-config-file), both in the root and on the conda environment, I have tried to reinstall fontconfig both in the root and on the conda environment, and I have also tried the answer suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100787/centos-and-fontconfig-cannot-load-default-config-file), and I have exited the console, and restart the machine several times, and I still get the same error.

I will very much appreciate any help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 11):

The following fixed it for me:

```
export FONTCONFIG_FILE=$CONDA_PREFIX/etc/fonts/fonts.conf
export FONTCONFIG_PATH=$CONDA_PREFIX/etc/fonts/
```

EDIT:
Can you try it again? There were two '\' too much.

Comment: Thank you Joachim for your answer. I tried these two lines, but I still get the same error.

Comment: `$CONDA_PREFIX` doesn't exist on my system (using conda, obviously), but manually typing in the path (e.g. `export FONTCONFIG_PATH=~/miniconda3/envs/science/etc/fonts/`) fix the problem...

Comment: Imho ```$CONDA_PREFIX``` exists only in a conda environment and not in the conda root environment.

Comment: I wanna give you a big hug. +1